# Obtaining odd p-values and no p-values after running bootstrapped regresions

Tags: r, regression, p-value, bootstrap, simulation

From this set of toy data:

```
> dput(ryder)
structure(list(tcount = 1:43, margin = c(7L, 2L, 6L, -1L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, -3L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
6L, 9L, 1L, -5L, -2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -3L, -9L, -9L, 
5L, -1L, -1L, -5L, 6L, -7L, 10L), tcount = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), home = c(12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 24L, 
    32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 20L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), europe = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), log(size) = c(1.07918124604762, 
    1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
    1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
    1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
    1.38021124171161, 1.50514997831991, 1.50514997831991, 1.50514997831991, 
    1.50514997831991, 1.50514997831991, 1.50514997831991, 1.50514997831991, 
    1.30102999566398, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 
    1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 
    1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 
    1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 
    1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222, 
    1.44715803134222, 1.44715803134222)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-43L))
```

I fit this simple OLS model

```
> fit=lm(margin~tcount+home+europe+log(size), data=ryder)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = margin ~ tcount + home + europe + log(size), data = ryder)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-10.748  -2.169  -0.074   2.299  10.270 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -12.256      6.200   -1.98   0.0554 .  
tcount        -0.140      0.126   -1.11   0.2720    
home           4.560      1.251    3.64   0.0008 ***
europe        -5.404      2.545   -2.12   0.0403 *  
log(size)      5.928      2.406    2.46   0.0184 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.1 on 38 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.505, Adjusted R-squared:  0.453 
F-statistic: 9.68 on 4 and 38 DF,  p-value: 1.69e-05
```

from which I ran 10,000 bootstrapped simulation runs in order to check the robustness of the data and the OLS model estimates

```
> library(car)
> bsfit=Boot(fit, R=10000)
> summary(bsfit, high.moments=TRUE)

Number of bootstrap replications R = 10000 
             original    bootBias  bootSE   bootMed  bootSkew bootKurtosis
(Intercept) -12.25579  0.02599064 5.38548 -12.45522  0.171672     0.175865
tcount       -0.14018 -0.00046868 0.15927  -0.13212 -0.186160    -0.054056
home          4.55964 -0.03996191 1.27603   4.52944 -0.061641     0.092715
europe       -5.40431 -0.06915570 2.92813  -5.48657  0.047148    -0.037596
log(size)     5.92844  0.00163010 2.44069   5.97726 -0.056764     0.133190

> with(bsfit, pnorm(abs((2*t0 - mean(t) - 1) / sqrt(var(t)[1,1])), lower.tail=F)*2)
 (Intercept)       tcount         home       europe    log(size) 
8.100632e-06 9.706015e-01 7.471309e-02 5.510074e-02 2.198957e-02
```

and produced a histogram plot of the bootstrapped estimates
[image]

My problem here is twofold:

1. The OLS and bootstrapped coefficients for 'home' are clearly statistically significant as they're 3.5 times their accompanying standard errors. This is also confirmed by the graph above (left panel, middle row), which clearly shows the BC(a) 95 per cent confidence intervals do **not** contain 0. Despite all this, the p-value is computed as 7.471309e-02 = 0.07471309 and therefore not clearing the *p* < 0.05 level. This doesn't make sense to me. What's going on here? What am I missing?
2. When I run 100,000 bootstrapped simulation runs, I obtain the following, for example:

```
> bsfit=Boot(fit, R=100001)
Loading required namespace: boot
> summary(bsfit, high.moments=TRUE)

Number of bootstrap replications R = 99996 
             original    bootBias  bootSE   bootMed  bootSkew bootKurtosis
(Intercept) -12.25579  0.03307437 5.41265 -12.37263  0.153903     0.224639
tcount       -0.14018 -0.00075596 0.16045  -0.13575 -0.165944    -0.019430
home          4.55964 -0.05710058 1.28518   4.51742 -0.061580     0.033152
europe       -5.40431 -0.06963547 2.95430  -5.49223  0.022428    -0.010192
log(size)     5.92844  0.00198483 2.45264   5.94888 -0.040956     0.173644

> with(bsfit, pnorm(abs((2*t0 - mean(t) - 1) / sqrt(var(t)[1,1])), lower.tail=F)*2)
(Intercept)      tcount        home      europe   log(size) 
         NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

I get no p-values for my coefficients at all! The same obtains when running 15,000, 25,000, 50,000 and 1 million simulation runs. Is there some sort of cut-off threshold above which you never get p-values? If there is, I've not been made aware of it! (Indeed, it even happens occasionally when running 10,000 simulations a second or third time.)

I'd be extremely grateful to anybody who can give some clear-minded insight as to why all this is happening, as well as some solutions.

Comment: What are the 2 and the -1 doing in `abs(2*t0-mean(t)-1)`? Did you do the plots of bootstrap results also for the large numbers of replications? Also in my R-world the `boot` command is not capitalised (I may not know the one you're using).

Comment: Please pay attention to the preceding comment by @Christian, because it explains everything.

Comment: I'd run `str(bsfit)` and look at the individual components, particularly `t`, to see whether they look OK and some explanation can be found.

Comment: @ChristianHennig @whuber: This solution now produces *p*-values 10 times too large with all effects now rendered insignificant! Odd? As I think the third code chunk makes clear, `Boot` comes from John Fox's `car` package in `R`, which calls the `boot` function and from which you can obtain a wider range of really nice graphics, such as the one in my original query. My second question, however, remains unanswered, even with the corrected `with` call: running 100,000 bootstrapped simulation runs again still returns a bunch of `NA` outputs for all of the variable columns. Is there a solution?

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHennig: I'll try that with `str(bsfit)`. The amended `with` call now produces p-values 10 times too large with all effects now rendered insignificant! But I know that the last three main effects *are* significant, so something's not quite right here!

Comment: Of course we don't know what the amended `with` call is if you don't tell us. Generally debugging code requires looking at everything and checking whether it takes the right values at every step, then trying to find explanations for why it takes the values it takes. That's hard to do in a forum like this for those who don't really work with your code.

Comment: @ChristianHennig: The amended `with` call was the one you suggested in your original answer, namely `with(bsfit, pnorm(abs(t0 - mean(t)) / sqrt(var(t)[1,1])), lower.tail=F)*2)` (in other words, removing the 2 and -1). I'm very confident that I'm not too far off a solution here!